# Why ProgressBar not gone?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my xml file:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_index"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_index"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset">
</ListView>
```

I try to `mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE)` after `mListView.setAdapter()` ,but when I check the "Show layout bounds" in the "Developer options".The layout not actually gone.As the picture shows,the ProgressBar is still in the center of the FrameLayout.Why?

[image]

Java code:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_index);
    mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity());
    new MyTask().execute();
    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList<NewsItem>> {
    protected ArrayList<NewsItem> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // some execution....
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<NewsItem> result) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your java code ?

Answer (score 2):

can you try this:

```
 ProgressDialog mProgress  = new ProgressDialog(activity.this);
 ........... 
 mProgress.dismiss();
```

Comment: you can create progress like this .(I edit my answer ) you do not need define it your layout? can you try that

Comment: thanks,it works but need to do some customization to make the background transparent.I still confused with why View.Gone not works?

Comment: I vote it up,but I want to know why View.GONE not works?

Comment: `ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_index);`
`bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` this should be worked, or you can use  `listview.setEmptyView(prog_bar);`

Comment: can you try `ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_index); ` this I mean `ProgressBar bar` is defined in method not outside

Comment: no problem, you can redefine it like `ProgressBar bar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_index);`and set view.gone **`OR`** you can use `final` before your definition like : `final ProgressBar bar`